# Database design suggestions for a configurable product eshop

Tags: database, database-design, schema

I am building an e-shop that will have configurable products. The configurable parts will need to have different prices and stocks from the main product.
What database design would be best in this case?

I started with something like this.

**Features**

- id
- name

**Features Options**

- id
- id_feature
- value

**Products**

- id
- name
- price

**Products Features**

- id
- id_product
- id_feature
- value ( save the value from the feature-options for ease in search )
- configurable (yes, no)

The problem is that now I am stuck on how to save the configurable product features.
I was thinking of saving their value as a json. But that will make saving price modification for a certain option difficult.

How would you go about this ?

Thank you.

Comment: wrote an article about the solution i adopted. http://www.gsdesign.ro/blog/database-design-example-for-a-configurable-product-eshop/

Comment: I added a comment on your blogpost. Personnally I think it would be good to start a new question and expose the solution you adopted in yor blog post with explanation, it'd be great :)

Comment: Hey sorry to bother you again, I commented your blogpost again, could you have look please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two more tables will do the magic (below). Hacks like JSON or parseable text fields can and should always be avoided.

```
  -- one product <id_product> can have multiple
  -- product variants <id> with different features  enabled
  product_variant
    id
    id_product (one product - many variants)

  -- features, enabled for certain <id_product_variant>
  product_variant_enabled_feature
    id
    id_product_variant (one variant - many features)
    id_product_feature
    unique_constraint(id_product_variant, id_product_feature)
```